# Can't record a 1080p video with the iOS Simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, quicktime, imovie

I am trying to record a video of my iOS game, using Quicktime Player, running the iPhone8Plus Simulator in a portrait mode which is supposed to produce a 1080px1920 video. However, the resolution I got is 750x1334 in iMovie after trying to share it as an App Preview.

Please, advise me on what I should do to get the required resolution.

Comment: Though the intention of the video is for the App Store, nothing in the question pertains to development. It is more about Quicktime Player and iMovie quirks. Perhaps better suited to apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you christopherdrum for your clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `xcrun simctl io recordVideo ...` to record your video.  You should tun off 'Optimize Rendering for Window Scale' in Simulator.app.